# how to change value data in array PHP?

Tags: php

I have a data array like this:

```
$data = array(1,2,3);
```

how to change the array like this:

```
$data = array('1','2','3');
```

Tanks Before

Comment: If your numbers are comming from variables you could do it like: $data = array(”{$a}”, ”{$b}”);

Answer (score 0):

You have to change type of all array values, just like this

```
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
  $data[$key] = (string) $val;
}
```

or

```
function convert2string($n)
{
    return (string) $n;
}

$a = [1, 2, 3];
$data = array_map('convert2string', $a);
```